# Sort an array and make it unique on multiple conditions - Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

This is a sample array example as Input :

```
hashForAnimals = [{ 
    :animalCd=>"Tiger",:animalType=>"Carnivore", :sortOrder =>3},
    {:animalCd=>"Cow",:animalType=>"Herbivore", :sortOrder =>5},
    {:animalCd=>"Rabbit", :animalType=>"Herbivore", :sortOrder =>2}, 
    {:animalCd=>"Shark",:animalType=>"Carnivore", :sortOrder =>4}, 
    {:animalCd=>"Cow",:animalType=>"Carnivore", :sortOrder =>1},
    {:animalCd=>"Bear", :animalType=>"Omnivore", :sortOrder =>7},
    {:animalCd=>"Tiger",:animalType=>"Carnivore", :sortOrder =>6}]
```

Expected Output:

```
hashForAnimals = [{
  :animalCd=>"Cow", :animalType=>"Carnivore",  :sortOrder =>1},
  {:animalCd=>"Rabbit", :animalType=>"Herbivore", :sortOrder =>2},
  {:animalCd=>"Tiger",:animalType=>"Carnivore", :sortOrder =>3},
  {:animalCd=>"Shark",:animalType=>"Carnivore", :sortOrder =>4},
  :animalCd=>"Cow", :animalType=>"Herbivore",  :sortOrder =>5}
  {:animalCd=>"Bear", :animalType=>"Omnivore", :sortOrder =>7}]
```

I need to sort the array on the basis of sort order and then I need to make the array unique with respect to animalCd falling under the same group i.e. animalType.

Tiger has appeared once with the minimum sort order, however Cow is appearing twice in the array but with different animalType.

It can be done by collecting the array into multiple animalType arrays and sorting and making them unique and merge back to a single array. However, I need an elegant solution for this.

Sample code that I'm trying:

```
hashForAnimals.sort!{|x,y| x[:sortOrder].to_i<=>y[:sortOrder].to_i}.group_by { |a| a[:animalType]}
```

I can group them into seperate hashes but then I need to make the individual hashes unique and then merge into the array.

Is this even possible in the way by which I'm approaching it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `sort_by` method and `uniq` and `values_at`

```
hashForAnimals.sort_by{ |a| a[:sortOrder] }.uniq{ |k| k.values_at(:animalCd, :animalType) }


# => [{:animalCd=>"Cow", :animalType=>"Carnivore", :sortOrder=>1}, {:animalCd=>"Rabbit", :animalType=>"Herbivore", :sortOrder=>2}, {:animalCd=>"Tiger", :animalType=>"Carnivore", :sortOrder=>3}, {:animalCd=>"Shark", :animalType=>"Carnivore", :sortOrder=>4}, {:animalCd=>"Cow", :animalType=>"Herbivore", :sortOrder=>5}, {:animalCd=>"Bear", :animalType=>"Omnivore", :sortOrder=>7}]
```

Comment: Did you try my last update, with `values_at` method ?

Comment: Was unaware of values_at API. Brilliant and thanks for the prompt reply!

Comment: There may be less to sort if you `uniq` before `sort` (and there's no reason to think `uniq` will be faster by doing it second).

Comment: What if i use uniq and delete element with more sortOrder ?

Comment: ...but my suggestion does affect which elements are selected by `uniq`, which may be important (don't know from the question).

Comment: About performance you are definitely right, but i think, he want keep object with smallest `:sortOrder`

Comment: 'hashForAnimals.uniq{ |k| [k[:animalCd], k[:animalType]] }.sort_by{ |a| a[:sortOrder] }' is more simpler and faster. For objects, we would require dot notations and for that sort and uniq separately.